# The real equation of a pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

In physics I never solve the equation $\ddot\theta = \sin(\theta)$. Instead, we used the approximation $\theta = \sin(\theta)$ for small angles and then it was easy to solve. I didn't do any physics since a while but I was interested by the original equation. I tried to solve it with formal series but it was quite ugly and I give up quickly. But maybe it's well known so I'm asking the question here :

> What are the solutions to the equation $\ddot\theta = \sin(\theta)$ ?

Comment: Take a look at the Wikipedia article on the pendulum, specifically the section titled [Arbitrary-amplitude period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_%28mathematics%29#Arbitrary-amplitude_period). As that article mentions, you need elliptic integrals to get the exact solution.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080558/an-elliptic-integral-of-first-kind-expresses-the-time-of-motion-along-an-ellipti/1083351#1083351

Comment: The exact solutions use *Jacobi's elliptic integrals of the first kind* $$F(k,\theta)=\displaystyle\int_0^{\theta}\dfrac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu t}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}},\quad(0<k<1).$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A first good step is multiplying by $2\dot{\theta}$, to get

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \dot{\theta}^2=2\sin \theta \dot{\theta} $$

which can be integrated to

$$\dot{\theta}^2=-2\cos \theta+A,$$

where $A$ is a constant. Thus

$$\frac{d \theta}{ \sqrt{A-2\cos \theta}}= \pm dt $$

and a second integration gives

$$F_A(\theta)=\pm(t-t_0) $$

where $F_A$ is a primitive function of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{A-2\cos \theta}}$ and $t_0$ is another constant.

**EDIT:** The solution given above is implicit for $\theta(t)$. Mathematica gives

$$\theta(t)= \pm 2 \text{am}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left(c_1-2\right) \left(t+c_2\right){}^2},-\frac{4}{c_1-2}\right) $$

where am is the [Jacobi Amplitude function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html).

Comment: Nice one, great answer. +1.

Comment: shouldn't there be a $2$ on the RHS of the first line?

Comment: @Dylan you're right, corrected!