# How to solve this ODE with sine of dependent variable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$ y’’ = \sin(y) $$

I cannot figure out how to even start. I came across this while dealing with Lagrangian mechanics.

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Multiplying both sides by $y'$ and integrate we have
$$\int y'y''dx=\int y'sin(y)dx$$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2}y'^2=-\cos(y)+C$$ so
$$y'=-2\cos(y)+2C_1$$
$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{-2\cos(y)+2C_1}}=\pm1$$
so we have
$$\int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{-2\cos(y)+2C_1}}dx=\pm\int 1dx$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Gosh, it looks trivial now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @UtkarshKumar: Except that the integral is not trivial, it's a so-called *elliptic integral*. See here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1083351/1242