# Is there an exact, analytical solution to $y'' = a\sin(y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the differential equation
$$
y'' = a\sin(y)
$$
when analyzing a problem with a pendulum. I tried checking it out in symbolab, and wolfram; however, both services exceeded computation time. I could think of a way to approximate it by taking the taylor series of $\sin(y)$ to a desired number of terms, but I wonder if there is an exact analytical solution that exists.

Comment: Wolfram isn't the best when it comes to handling arbitrary constants. Plugging in specific values for $a$, e.g. $1$ or $2$, give "exact" answers in terms of the [Jacobi amplitude function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html), e.g. $a=1$ gives

$$y(x) = -2 \cdot \text{am} \left( \frac 1 2 \sqrt{(c_1 - 2) (x + c_2)^2} \;\middle|\; \frac{-4}{c_1 - 2} \right)$$

according to Wolfram. (I don't claim to know enough about this to know if it's good enough for your uses.)

Comment: @PrincessEev: Adjusting generalizing what you found to a generic $a$ gives $y(x)=-2\cdot\text{am}\left(\frac12\sqrt{(c_1-2a)(x+c_2)^2} \; \middle|\;\frac{-4a}{c_1-2a}\right)$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080558/an-elliptic-integral-of-first-kind-expresses-the-time-of-motion-along-an-ellipti/1083351), for example. And some other [similar question](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+pendulum+elliptic).

Answer (score 2):

If you switch variables $$y'' = a\sin(y)$$ becomes
$$-\frac {x''}{[x']^3}=a \sin(y)$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$ gives
$$-\frac{p'}{p ^3}=a \sin(y)\quad \implies \quad p=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt{c_1-2a\cos(y)}}$$

Integrating, you will face an elliptic integral
$$x+c_2=\pm\frac{2 }{\sqrt{c_1-2 a}}F\left(\frac{y}{2}~\bigg|~\frac{4 a}{2 a-c_1}\right)$$

If you take the inverse, you face the amplitude for Jacobi elliptic functions.

Comment: I edited the last line of your answer a bit to make it more pretty. If you don't like my edit you can roll it back.

Comment: @K.defaoite. Thank you ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I am solving a differential equation by using Jacobi elliptic functions. They don't teach them in high school.

Let $am(u)$, $sn(u)$, $cn(u)$, $dn(u)$ denote Jacobi elliptic functions with modulus $k$. They are defined by

$$u=∫_0^{{am(u)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2φ}}dφ,$$
$$sn(u)=\sin(am(u)),$$
$$cn(u)=\cos(am(u)),$$
$$dn(u)=\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2φ}.$$

Then,
$$(am(u))′=dn(u)$$ and
$$(am(u))′′=-k^2sn(u)cn(u)$$ or equivalently
$$(2am(u))′′=-k^2\sin(2am(u)).$$

Let
$y=\pm 2am(c_1u+c_2)\tag{1}$
with modulus  $k=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a}}{c_1}$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. Then $y′′=a\sin y$. So, I think $(1)$ is the general solution. I do not know if one of these ±'s is necessary.